# How join to excel table in c# base on common column?

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

**Here is my to excel sheets :**

[image: Sheet one]

[image: Sheet two]

And here is the code I used in c# to read them:

```
                _ds = new DataSet();
                _tb = new DataTable();

                var myConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + OFD.FileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
                var myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ["+SheetName+"$]", myConnection);
                myCommand.Fill(_tb);
                _ds.Tables.Add(_tb);
                // _bs.DataSource = _ds.Tables[0];

                DataTable Sheet0 = _ds.Tables[0];
```

**My question is**: how can I join these two based on **NID** and display result in DataGrid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

joining tables that imported from Excel is no different from usual join but there is trick. these tables should have a **Primary-Key** column. 
Then in your case first we set the "id" column as Primary-Key:

```
Sheet0.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { Sheet0.Columns["NID"] };
```

Remember: **NID** column values should be unique **AND** you should do this for other tables too. 
After setting primary-key you can use join or merge your tables. I use merge method cause it's simpler one. :) :

```
    var _TableAll = Sheet0.Copy();
   _TableAll.Merge(_Table2);
```

There is question posted here about [join method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439616/help-understanding-enumerable-join-method) if you are interested. You can check it out.
I hope this help.